# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath for one section iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image: Section one here]

[image: Section two here]

As you can see in the images, there are two sections in this tableView.
May I know how to manage to enable the editActionsForRowAtIndexPath in section one only?

Here is my code that enable the tableViewCell to have a row swipe...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
{
    let complete =  UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Complete")
    { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    complete.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    return [complete]
}
```

Comment: you can add the filter to your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` method like `if indexPath.section == 0 {...}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use indexPath.section to decide which section you are setting, but you should use `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:indexPath:` to tell the table view when you want to enable editing.

**Swift 2**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool{
    return indexPath.section == 0
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return indexPath.section == 0
}
```

Comment: Yes, this one works perfectly! This logic makes me learn a new thing

Comment: `return indexPath.section == 0` is enough