# Swift 3 how to have delete cell button like iOS mail application (image and text )

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmqbn.jpg)

How can I have a swipe delete cell button like iOS mail application(image + text )?

I found this method but my image is not scale to size:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {  
    let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title:"\nDelete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
    self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(self.tableView,commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
            forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

    return
})

    deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "icon")!)
    return [deleteButton]
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am little confused with your explanation. If you can please provide some more explanation regarding button you want. Do you want Standard button which iOS provides itself or you want a customize button? 
I am trying to address both aspects below.

If you need standard operation you can do it like this:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            // remove the item from the array if you want
            array.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            // delete the table view row
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        }
    }

}
```

Also, i would like to recommend [This.](https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)

If u just want to resize button image you can do it like this:

```
deleteButton.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Hi, i am trying to add a button that look just like the one on iphone mail app. with both the bin image and the delete text. the method you provided shows just the delete button. was wondering if i can add an image with the bin together

Comment: Can u attach screen shot of your button after setting image in its background ?

Comment: Morever, please check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575691/editactionsforrowatindexpath-for-one-section-ios-swift

Comment: Your [This] tag helped me a lot. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The table view will do that for you. You just need to have your table view/table view controller live in a navigation stack so there's a navigation bar, and then implement a couple of methods: `tableView(_, canEditRowAt:)` and `tableView(_:,commit:forRowAt:)`.

You'll probably want to add an edit button to your navigation bar.

I just pushed a demo project called [**MasterDetailSwift**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/MasterDetailSwift.git) that supports adding and removing cells to a table view. (It also shows the master/detail UI pattern, a good way to handle prepareForSegue using a switch statements, and a few other useful techniques.)

Comment: I think you misread the question. The issue appears to be from the attempt to set an image on the delete button.

Comment: @rmaddy, I took it to mean that the OP thought he had to create a custom button in order to add a delete feature, not knowing that table views provide it for free.

Comment: To the OP, is it a requirement that you install a custom image in the delete button, or are you just looking to add a delete button?

Comment: Look at the picture. The OP doesn't want the single standard Delete button. They are implementing `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`. This allows for several button like in the photo.

Comment: i am actually trying to add 2 button with image and text just like the photo but if i try to use this method
deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "icon")!)
the image does not fit the standard button size